# Get last non-empty cell in a row or get last column with a non-empty header in Excel

Tags: c#, .net, excel, interop

How to get last column in Excel with a non-empty header or cell? In other words, get last non-empty cell in header row of Excel to get the respective column index in number.

Can't really find how to do that in C#. In VBA, it is rather simple using XlToleft.

I am using .NET and Excel interop.

Answer (score 0):

Do not click on row that is to be left completely blank. E.g.: If your data ends at row 8, do not click in row 9 or 10 or any row greater than that. As excel sheet counts these rows and sends blank.

`If you are using OLEDB connection it reads that blank row and column only if you have clicked on a single cell in that row or column`

or

Check for null explicitly through your code.

Comment: Yes, that can be done like take a range of header row and check for last nul. Although,what I am looking for a sophisticated way to do this.Exactly the way, you can do it in VBA using XlToleft.

In addition, as I said earlier I am using interop not OLEDB.

Comment: and I am a bit confused here, what do you mean by click here. In my case, everything is happening in background so there is no question of clicking something or even opening Excel application itself.